# I need to put a text in a SPAN tag using the Gecko

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I need to put a text in a `span` tag using Gecko. I already researched at all and can not find a solution to this.
If was input or textarea would be easy.
Html page that need to automate.

```
<div class="_5rpb">
    <div aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="js_2g" class="_5rpu" contenteditable="true" role="combobox" spellcheck="true" style="outline: none; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
        <div data-contents="true">
            <div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="ed503" data-offset-key="aqkh3-0-0">
                <div data-offset-key="aqkh3-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj">
                    <span data-offset-key="aqkh3-0-0">
                        <span data-text="true">**TEST HERE**</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the InnerHtml property of this element to be whatever you need.

Comment: Hello Friend. Thanks for the reply but this element has no NAME and has no ID